# Проблема с префабом Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я создаю игру с мультиплеером в юнити на фотоне 2, для того чтобы сделать спавн, я сделал префаб персонажа, но так же на этом префабе у меня стоит скрипт с управлением, в который я должен добавить кое что, что бы все заработало, но прикол в том, что я это не могу сделать, ибо юнити блокирует переноску объекта из сцены в префаб. Что мне делать?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142799/discussion-on-question-by-maxim-br----unity); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GameObject.Find("joyStick").GetComponent<joyStick>();
```

Ответ

Answer (score -1):

joyStick = GameObject.Find("JoyStick").GetComponent();
TouchField = GameObject.Find("Touching").GetComponent();